# How do you automatically test a web application?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, web-applications

I have recently learned how to use python unittest to do automated testing on functions. But it got me thinking, how do you test the functionality of a web application? Do you test UI, backend APIs and business logic etc individually?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the following python frameworks:

Web UI testing - https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/

Backend testing - https://github.com/svanoort/pyresttest